# Eclipse-based IDE development

Tags: eclipse, ide

I've developed a compiler for a static-typed language using eclipse ad its ANTLR plugin. And now I'm interested to know whether it's possible to develop an IDE for this language as an eclipse plugin. Is there any tool for developing eclise-based IDEs compliant with ANTLR grammars?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [Xtext](https://www.eclipse.org/Xtext/), which is a framework for developing language tools (including IDEs).
There are plenty of SO questions about it and how it relates to/uses ANTLR. For example:

- [Convert simple Antlr grammar to Xtext](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8279790/convert-simple-antlr-grammar-to-xtext)
- [What are features of ANTLR that XText Does not provide?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5904625/what-are-features-of-antlr-that-xtext-does-not-provide)